# Create an img element into <a> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to embed an image inside an  tag after the image on  tag loaded.

So the sequence goes like this...

```
<a id="anchorID">
  <img onload="MyFunc(anchorID)>IMAGE1</img>
     //..After image 1 loaded add
     <img>IMAGE2</img>
</a>

<script>
 function MyFunc(anchorID)
{
  var anchorElement = document.getElementById(anchorID);
      //I want to create an image tag inside the anchorElement
}
</script>
```

Thanks for the help.. T_T

Comment: can you please expalain why you want this multiple image tags inside anchor tag??

Comment: `img` is self closing tag `<img />`

Comment: Do you want `src` attributes on those image tags?

Comment: 1.) I want multiple image tags sinec the second img tag is like a stamp
2.) Noted sir. Thanks for pointing out
3.) Yes sir I will update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution, just add `onload="addNextImage('#id_in_which_to_add_new_image', 'second_image_url')"` to the image you want to load first. In the next example, ignore the width and style (I put them there to be able to test the functionality, making the image smaller so I don't need to scroll to see the behavior - I chose a huge image to make sure everything works as it should, and the border makes it appear sort of like a progress bar =)

```
<script>
    function addNextImage(selector, url) {
        var where = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (where) {
            var newImage = document.createElement('img');
            newImage.src = url;
            where.appendChild(newImage);
        }
    }
</script>
<a id="anchorID">
    <img onload="addNextImage('#anchorID', 'http://animalia-life.com/data_images/wallpaper/tiger-wallpaper/tiger-wallpaper-01.jpg')" src="http://hubblesource.stsci.edu/events/iyafinale/support/documents/gal_cen-composite-9725x4862.png" width="400px" style="border: 1px solid black" />
</a>
```

This should work on most browsers today: IE8+ (as long as you use basic CSS2.1 selectors as the first argument), and pretty much everything else in use. (IE8+ because it depends on [querySelector](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector))

Comment: Sir why does my function gives me uncaught reference error someimtes

Comment: Is it because of my cache??

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the error. What browser are you using, how did you add the script (and where), what exactly is the reference that's causing the ReferenceError?

Comment: MyFunc was not defined

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

Javascript appendChild()

```
var node = document.createElement("img");//Create a <img> node
node.src="SomeImageURL";
firstImage.appendChild(node);
```

JQuery append()

```
$("#firstImageID").append("<img src="SomeImageURL"/>");
```

see links for more info

[Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

[jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp)

Comment: Thank you sir one last question, How am I able to prevent uncaught reference error. since it gives me that error sometimes

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to add an image to the anchor tag

```
function MyFunc(anchorID) {
    var anchorElement = document.getElementById(anchorID);
    if (anchorElement) {
        //I want to create an image tag inside the anchorElement
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "yourImagePath");
        anchorElement.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The `<img>` will be appended to the `<a>` element rather than inside it

Comment: Appending the img to the a tag means adding the img tag inside the a tag. So you will end up with <a><img></a>. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you sir one last question, How am I able to prevent uncaught reference error. since it gives me that error sometimes

Comment: is it because of my cache?

Comment: This could be due to the element with anchorID not existing in the DOM. Try doing a check on the anchorElement before using it to make sure its defined.

Comment: how would I do that sir?

Comment: By checking if the anchorElement is defined. See the updated post.